# Blender Game Engine - bge Module Not found

Tags: python, blender, bpy

I have looked at other forums and did not find an answer to my problem, i know that for bge the script only works when connected to logic bricks, and just to be sure i was typing it the right way i watched a bge tutorial on youtube and it worked for him but not for me.

how do i download the bge module?
any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

also i noticed after i watched the video the blender console said this:

Error:

```
Python script error - object 'Cube', controller 'Python':
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "moveX.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'Bge'
Blender Game Engine Finished
```

---

Script:

```
import bge

def main():
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    owner = cont.owner  
    owner.positive.x += 0.1

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the bge module is a part of the game engine and is available through a python controller logic brick. This python controller is only activated when the game engine is actually running.

While you can build blender without the game engine I wouldn't expect it to be disabled unless you have compiled your own version of blender. The error you see will always happen if you run a script using bge outside of the game engine, such as from blender's text editor.

First enable the game engine by selecting it in the render engine menu.

[image: render engine menu]

Then after setting up your script in the python controller, press <kbd>P</kbd> to start the game engine.

**EDIT:**

The error in your question indicates you have `import Bge` in your script, the `bge` should be all lowercase, which you seem to have fixed in the script you added. The script will get a different error as there is no `positive` property in an object, you will want to use `owner.position.x`

```
import bge

def main():
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    owner = cont.owner  
    owner.position.x += 0.1

main()
```

Comment: and thats why i don't understand why it's not working. i have an always sensor on the script with true pulse to move me 0.1 blender units on the x axis, and because it is an always sensor for as long as i have the bge running i get this message in the console: Python script error - object 'Cube', controller 'Python':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "moveX.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "moveX.py", line 8, in main
AttributeError: 'KX_GameObject' object has no attribute 'positive'
Blender Game Engine Finished

Comment: same as the one i posted above

Comment: i think i know what the problem is the guy i was watching the tutorial from posibly has an onlder version of python and the syntax was changed from now, so can you help me i will post the script in the post above